# cordova-plugin-file --- Download de arquivo fora da pasta do APP - Ionic 2/3

Tags: ionic, ionic2, ionic3, cordova-plugin

Galera gostaria de um help, necessito salvar arquivos que o usuario baixe do app no dispositivo, porem fora da pasta do app.

Todos os caminhos do plugin file. Exemplo: cordova.file.dataDirectory
Não me atende, gostaria de saber se tem como criar uma pasta dentro da pasta PICTURE semelhante ao que o facebook, messenger, whatsapp faz.

Comment: - ESTA DÚVIDA FOI RESOLVIDA!!! - VLW

Comment: Legal! Você poderia adicionar a solução no campo de respostas? Dessa maneira você pode ajudar pessoas com o mesmo problema.

Comment: estou precisando também